# Jasper : use different connections between report and subreport

Tags: jasper-reports

First, I search and found some similar topics to have an answer. The problem is that none of the propositions worked for me ...
Let me explain my situation.

I have a main report which contains a subreport. The main report retrieves data from a CSV file aned the subreport from an Oracle Database. I have done a Oracle DataAdapTer.
I work with TIBCO JasperSoft Studio because iReport does not know jdbc.oracle ...

The main report : [image] I put the entire image to show the interface, the configuration ... Maybe it can help you.

The subreport : [image]

Independently, reports work perfectly.
The main report (without subreport) works : [image]

And the subreport works too : [image]

As you can say in the first image, I want to have my subreport in the main report.
To do this I tried to set a **Connection Expression** like this : *java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//SERVER:PORT/DBNAME", "USER", "PASSWORD")*
I tried differents syntaxes without result, I always have this exception :

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//SERVER:PORT/DBNAME", "USER", "PASSWORD")
        at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.fillReport(ReportControler.java:548)   
[...]
```

EDIT to say that in the error I see : "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@//172.10.10.0:1521/instance". It let me to think that my **ojdbc6-11.jar** is not well added to the project/jaspersoft.
How to install the driver properly ?

I rely on you to help me, I do not find out my mistake.

Thanks,

Damien.

Answer (score -1):

If these two reports share the same connection, you can pass the connection from the main report to the sub report by using the parameter variable `$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}`

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have two different connections, one from a CSV file and an other from an Oracle Database. So this parameter does not match for my need.